# Replacing group of words in a text file using shell script

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I want to replace value(ifqlen) 50 with "Value(ifqlen) 25" "Value(ifqlen) 75" "Value(ifqlen) 100" in a text file with below content

> set val(ifqlen) 50;
>
> set opt(x) 652;
>
> set opt(y) 752;
>
> set stopTime 999;
>
> $new config -protype(ll) \
>
> ```
>      -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
> ```

for which the perl script I used is with for loop as mentioned below:

```
for i in 25 50 75 100

do

    perl -pi -e "s/val\(ifqlen\) \K50/$i/g" /home/guest/Desktop/file.txt
    #perform logic#
    perl -pi -e "s/val\(ifqlen\) \K$i/50/g" /home/guest/Desktop/file.txt

done
```

OUTPUT: when for loop is executed for first time is perfect

OUTPUT: when for loop is executed for second time

> set val(ifqlen) 25;
>
> set opt(x) 652;
>
> set opt(y) 752;
>
> set stopTime 999;
>
> $new config -protype(ll) \
>
> ```
>      -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) **25\**
> ```

OUTPUT: when for loop is executed for third time

> set val(ifqlen) 2525;
>
> set opt(x) 652;
>
> set opt(y) 752;
>
> set stopTime 999;
>
> $new config -protype(ll) \
>
> ```
>      -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) **2525\**
> ```

DESIRED OUTPUT

> set val(ifqlen) 25; #second time 50; #Third time 75 and lastly 100;#
>
> set opt(x) 652;
>
> set opt(y) 752;
>
> set stopTime 999;
>
> $new config -protype(ll) \
>
> ```
>      -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
> ```

@BroSlow:

have entered the code in test.sh file as below

for i in 25 50 75 100;

do

while read -r line;

do

```
echo "$line" | sed -e "s/set val(ifqlen) .*;/set val(ifqlen) 100;/"
```

done < "/home/makodia/Desktop/file.txt"

done

THIS DISPLAY THE CONTENT ON TERMINAL. TEXT FILE REMAINS UNCHANGED. WHAT TO DO FURTHER? SHOWS PERFECT RESULT ON TERMINAL.

SOLUTION WHICH I AM USING:

perl -pi -e "s/val(xyz) \K50/100/g" /home/guest/Desktop/text.tcl

perform logic;

perl -pi -e "s/val(xyz) \K100/50/g" /home/guest/Desktop/text.tcl

Comment: Do `./whatever_you_called_above_script > newfilename`. I updated a possible solution that writes from in script, but again blanking files in-script can cause issues, piping to a new file name and then doing whatever with it is safer.

Comment: Have added the solution at the bottom which i am using.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're trying to do with perl or why you're using it, but judging by your desired output you may want something like below. Could probably be even simpler, but really am confused what you're trying to do. Note `${line/something/somethingelse}` uses bash substitution and replaces something with somethingelse within variable "$line" (the * matches anything between the space after `val(ifqlen)` and the next occurance of `;`). Also the `-r` on `read` is needed so it ignores your escape characters.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for i in 25 50 75 100; do
  while read -r line; do
    echo "${line/set val(ifqlen) *;/set val(ifqlen) $i;}"
  done < "/home/guest/Desktop/file.txt"
done
```

Example output

```
> ./abovescript
set val(ifqlen) 25;

set opt(x) 652;

set opt(y) 752;

set stopTime 999;

$new config -protype(ll) \

     -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
set val(ifqlen) 50;

set opt(x) 652;

set opt(y) 752;

set stopTime 999;

$new config -protype(ll) \

     -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
set val(ifqlen) 75;

set opt(x) 652;

set opt(y) 752;

set stopTime 999;

$new config -protype(ll) \

     -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
set val(ifqlen) 100;

set opt(x) 652;

set opt(y) 752;

set stopTime 999;

$new config -protype(ll) \

     -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
```

Alternatively to the bash substituion you could also use either

```
echo "$line" | sed -e "s/set val(ifqlen) .*;/set val(ifqlen) $i;/"
```

or

```
sed -e "s/set val(ifqlen) .*;/set val(ifqlen) $i;/" <<< "$line"
```

**Update**

You can just read the file in at once to a variable, and then `read` from the variable and write to the file. Objectively this isn't the best option, as it can empty your file and fail to write to it, thus leaving you with just an empty file (even with the `cp` if your file was originally empty). It will also have buffering issues for very large files.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
input=$(<"/home/guest/Desktop/file.txt")
cp /home/guest/Desktop/file.txt /home/guest/Desktop/.backup_file.txt
: > "/home/guest/Desktop/file.txt"
for i in 25 50 75 100; do
  while read -r line; do
    echo "$line" | sed -e "s/set val(ifqlen) .*;/set val(ifqlen) $i;/" >> "/home/guest/Desktop/file.txt"
  done < "$input"
done
```

Comment: I am trying to simulate my project script. Scenario is i need to simulate the same script again and again by changing few parameters within the script and note down the simulation result.

Comment: I am using nested "for" loop. Total of 7 parameters are to be changes in a text file. so have placed 7 different for loops and keep on editing the text as per looping and keep on simulating it.

Comment: while running the above code it reflects error "Bad substitution" on the line containing 'echo'!

Comment: @Makodia Guessing you're either not running it from bash or you have an old version. Though if needed you can just do the same thing using `sed`, see the update in my answer.

Comment: have edited the question. Kindly look into it. sed works fine, but the replaced content is displayed on the terminal. text file remain unchanged.

Comment: @Makodia Updated answer. Note, if I was you I would just `>` the output of the original script to a new file name and then copy it over later if I wanted, as this will be safer than blanking the file in script. There may also be some way to just write in place once and append after with just `sed`, but not one that I know of offhand.